# Processing encoded json response from ajax request in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to make a ajax request using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/src/ax_query_places",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        query: value
    },
    success: function(response) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    failure: function() {
        alert('Could not get airports');
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

I am encoding the json on server side.
The json data received on response is :

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "name": "New\x20Orleans,\x20US\x20\x28New\x20Lakefront\x20\x2D\x20NEW\x29",
            "code": "NEW"
        },
        {
            "name": "New\x20Bedford,\x20US\x20\x28All\x20Airports\x20\x2D\x20EWB\x29",
            "code": "EWB"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I am receiving error every time.
Please suggest if there is a mistake in syntax. Or how should I parse the encoded response?

Also if I remove the encoding of json on the server side, everything works fine.

Comment: And what error are you getting? Posting the actual error would be more helpful than anything else you've posted ?

Comment: to parse json, you can use $.parseJSON() method

Comment: It should be noted that there is no `failure` property, so you can remove that, it will never be fired.

Comment: Do you get your json from server side on client side or you just dump   on server side?

Comment: Please look @ your network tab in your browsers dev tools, to tell us: What causes the error and which error was thrown. We need more information (like Http-Status-Code & parameter encoding), since the only possible solution is that your error occurs on the server side.

Comment: @wolle Response header : Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Type application/json
Date Fri, 01 Aug 2014 06:21:40 GMT
Expires Sat, 1-Jan-2000 12:00:00 GMT
Pragma no-cache
Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding chunked

Request header :
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @adeneo : The response in the network tab shows the encoded json that I have pasted. And the alert "Error" is getting displayed. No error is displayed

Comment: how are you encoding the json on the server?

Comment: I am using java ESAPI.encoder().encodeForJavaScript(value) for encoding json

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to have a List of "places" and the "places" class will contain two properties "name" and "code".

In that case, first create a class named "places" with two properties as "name" and "code" (names should match)

From client side, send `data: { query: JSON.stringify(value) }`

catch a string value as parameter in server side. So, your method deceleration will be -

```
public YourReturnType YourMethodName(string query)
```

Inside that, use the following code -

```
var javaScriptSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var values = javaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<List<places>>(query);
```

You will get serialized JSON in values.

Hope this helps!